# Regular expression help in java

Tags: java, regex

I am lost when it comes to building regex strings. I need a regular expression that does the following.

I have the following strings:

```
[~class:obj]
[~class|class2|more classes:obj]
[!class:obj]
[!class|class2|more classes:obj]
[?method:class]
[text]
```

A string can have multiple of whats above. Example string would be "[if] [!class:obj]"

I want to know what is in between the [] and broken into match groups. For example, the first match group would be the symbol if present (~|!|?) next what is before the : so that could be class or class|class2|etc... then what is on the right of the : and stop before the ].  There may be no : and what goes before it, but just something between the [].

So, how would I go about writing this regex?  And is it possible to give the match group names so I know what it matched?

This is for a java project.

Comment: Will text like [[this]] (i.e. nested braces) appear anywhere? If so, this is probably something you don't want to do with regex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure enough of your inputs, you can probably use something like `/\[(\~|\!|\?)?(?:((?:[^:\]]*?)+):)?([^\]]+?)\]/`. (to translate that into Java, you'll want to escape the backslashes and use quotation marks instead of forward slashes)

Comment: Cool. Thanks. now, when it matches something like [~class:obj] it gets the matches of, 1. ~ 2. class: 3. obj. On number 2, it captured the : How do you omit the :? Thanks.

Comment: Another note: at the beginning, you could probably just use `([~!?])` instead of `(\~|\!|\?)`. It's probably cleaner.

Comment: There is one issue with this regex. when I give it a string of "[if] [!class:obj]" it matches like this http://rubular.com/r/WMKMcHuwXU.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some web sites that might be helpful:

- http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html
- http://txt2re.com/index.php3?s=Test+test+june+2011+test&submit=Show+Matches
- http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee that is the one I have been using for a while.

Comment: Here's one that teaches regex very well (as opposed to those sites listed): http://codular.com/regex

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should work:

```
/[(.*?)(?:\|(.*?))*]/
```

Also:

```
[a-z]*
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
final Pattern
  outerP = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]"),
  innerP = Pattern.compile("\\[([~!?]?)([^:]*):?(.*)\\]");
for (String s : asList(
    "[~class:obj]",
    "[if][~class:obj]",
     "[~class|class2|more classes:obj]",
     "[!class:obj]",
     "[!class|class2|more classes:obj]",
     "[?method:class]",
     "[text]"))
{
  final Matcher outerM = outerP.matcher(s);
  System.out.println("Input: " + s);
  while (outerM.find()) {
    final Matcher m = innerP.matcher(outerM.group());
    if (m.matches()) System.out.println(
       m.group(1) + ";" + m.group(2) + ";" + m.group(3));
    else System.out.println("No match");
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated the code to clearly distinguish separate [] blocks in a single string. I think you'll realize this is an important aspect of the solution, as opposed to receiving just a flat sequence of matches.